# manipulate nested array of objects to access children values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a nested array of objects:

```
const nestArray = [
   {
      title: "title 1",
      children: [
         {
            title: "title 1-1",
            children: [
               { title: "title 1-1-1", children: [...] },
               { title: "title 1-1-2", children: [...] }
            ]
         },
         {
            title: "title 1-2",
            children: [
               { title: "title 1-2-1", children: [...] },
               { title: "title 1-2-2", children: [...] }
            ]
         },
      ]
   },
   {...},
   {...}
]
```

All objects have the same interface:

```
interface Obj {
   title: string
   children: Obj[]
}
```

I need to put a new key into each object called `keys`.
The `keys` will keep all its children's titles alongside its own title. So the final result should be:

```
const nestArray = [
   {
      title: "title 1",
      keys: ["title 1", "title 1-1", "title 1-1-1", "title 1-1-2"],
      children: [
         {
            title: "title 1-1",
            keys: ["title 1-1", "title 1-1-1", "title 1-1-2"],
            children: [
               { title: "title 1-1-1", keys: ["title 1-1-1"], children: [] },
               { title: "title 1-1-2", keys: ["title 1-1-2"], children: [] }
            ]
         },
         {
            title: "title 1-2",
            keys: ["title 1-2", "title 1-2-1", "title 1-2-2"],
            children: [
               { title: "title 1-2-1", keys: ["title 1-2-1"], children: [] },
               { title: "title 1-2-2", keys: ["title 1-2-2"], children: [] }
            ]
         },
      ]
   },
   {...},
   {...}
]
```

so the interface will be changed as:

```
interface Obj {
   title: string
   children: Obj[]
   keys: string[]
}
```

> I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution on the internet. I tried to solve this problem on my own, using recursive functions but still, I couldn't do it.

> Using lodash is fine

### What i've tried so far:

```
const mapTitlesToKeys = (obj) => {
  obj.keys = [obj.title];
  obj.children.forEach((childObj) => {
    mapTitlesToKeys(childObj);
    obj.keys.push(childObj.title);
  });
};

nestArray.forEach((obj) => {
  mapTitlesToKeys(obj);
});

console.log(nestArray);
```

results in:

```
[
   {
      title: "title 1",
      keys: ['title 1', 'title 1-1', 'title 1-2'], // <-- should be ["title 1", "title 1-1", "title 1-1-1", "title 1-1-2"]
      children: [
         {
            title: "title 1-1",
            keys: ['title 1-1', 'title 1-1-1', 'title 1-1-2'], // <-- should be ["title 1-1", "title 1-1-1", "title 1-1-2"]
            children: [
              {
                title: "title 1-1-1",
                keys: ["title 1-1-1"], // <-- fine
                children: []
              },
              {
                title: "title 1-1-2",
                keys: ["title 1-1-2"], // <-- fine
                children: []
              }
            ]
         },
         {
            title: "title 1-2",
            keys:  ['title 1-2', 'title 1-2-1', 'title 1-2-2'], // <-- should be ["title 1-2", "title 1-2-1", "title 1-2-2"] 
            children: [
              {
                title: "title 1-2-1",
                keys: ["title 1-2-1"], // <-- fine
                children: []
              },
              {
                title: "title 1-2-2",
                keys: ["title 1-2-2"], // <-- fine
                children: []
              }
            ]
         },
      ]
   },
   {...},
   {...}
]
```

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: sorry. the things I've tried aren't really worth putting in this post. do you agree to ignore them?

Comment: recursion may be one possible way to achieve this. Will give it a shot. Also - the idea of stackoverflow is to help our community members share what they've tried - and others may be able to provide targeted guidance based on what's tried.

Comment: you're completely right. i edited my post and you can take a glance at them

Comment: Under the `title: "title 1"` they keys need to include the items from both `1-1` and `1-2` --> in the above question, right?

Comment: my bad, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const addKeysTo = arr => (
  arr.map(
    ({ title, children }) => {
      const cArr = addKeysTo(children);
      keys = [title, ...cArr.flatMap(({ keys }) => keys )];
      return ({ title, keys, children: cArr });
    }
  )
);
/* explanation of the method
// method to add "keys" array to each elt
const addKeysTo = arr => (
  // use ".map()" to iterate over given array
  arr.map(
    // destructure to access "title", "children"
    ({ title, children }) => {
      // recurse to obtain updated childre-narray
      const cArr = addKeysTo(children);
      // construct "keys" array for current elt
      keys = [title, ...cArr.flatMap(({ keys }) => keys )];
      // explicit return of current elt of "arr" array with "keys" prop
      return ({ title, keys, children: cArr });
    }
  )   // implicit return from the method
);
*/
const nestArray = [{
  title: "title 1",
  children: [{
      title: "title 1-1",
      children: [{
          title: "title 1-1-1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          title: "title 1-1-2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 1-2",
      children: [{
          title: "title 1-2-1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          title: "title 1-2-2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}];

console.log(
  'added keys to nested-objects array...\n',
  addKeysTo(nestArray)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Comment: amazing solution. while it doesn't change or affect the original array and returns a new one. thank you so much.

Comment: Something I've learned rather recently - if we need to keep the original object or array as-is and obtain something new, one very simple way is to use [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). While the above solution creates a copy by spreading (`...`) at an element-level appears to work, if we simply did `structuredClone(arr).map` at the first-line - it will also ensure that the original `arr` remains unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (Shorter version... No need to keep the old one)

```js
const nestArray = [{
  title: "title 1",
  children: [{
      title: "title 1-1",
      children: [{
          title: "title 1-1-1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          title: "title 1-1-2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 1-2",
      children: [{
          title: "title 1-2-1",
          children: []
        },
        {
          title: "title 1-2-2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}]

function add_keys_obj(obj) {
  obj.keys = [obj.title];
  obj.children.forEach(function(child) {
    add_keys_obj(child)
    obj.keys.push(...child.keys)
  })
}

function add_keys(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(obj, key) {
    add_keys_obj(obj);
  })
  return arr;
}


add_keys(nestArray)
document.querySelector("pre").innerText = JSON.stringify(nestArray, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I'm improving the code, needs a little shortening so check it out later. Or try yourself even.